# Enviar un archivo (imagen) con POST en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

mi problema surge con lo siguiente. Estoy tratando de mandar una imagen que esta previamente cargada en un picturebox a través de un "POST" para subirlo a un servidor, como tal he empezado el código de esta manera.

```
string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");


        HttpWebRequest ObjRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
        ObjRequest.Method = "POST";
        ObjRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
        ObjRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
```

Nunca había subido una imagen como tal a un servidor, únicamente cadenas de texto, el cual resolvía así:

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(global.url + "nombreUri");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer "; //+ _token;
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";                                             
        httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(getJSON()); //<--- Recibimos el dato string del nombre, para escribirlo en una cadena stream/secuencia
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); //<---- Obtenemos la respuesta de la petición 
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) //<--- Leemos la respuesta, asignandola al objeto de StreamReader
        {
            setPlate(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Entonce mi duda surge a partir de esto, pues no se como lo enviaría, y me gustaría saber como resolverlo. Soy nuevo en esto y agradecería mucho su apoyo.

Comment: Si usas MySQL como base de datos entonces tiene que ser de tipo BLOB tu campo y pasarlo por Json en formato base64, edita tu pregunta y puedes poner como estas recibiendo los datos en el lado del server.

Comment: Como tal la imagen si había pensando en descomponer en base 64, pero no creyendo que se subiría a una BD en MySQL. Al final me dijeron que se tiene que subir "completa" la imagen a un servidor, del cual ya tengo su url.

Comment: es sencillo enviar la imagen solo que le faltan datos a tu pregunta, quien recibira tu imagen en el server? es una API, es un crud etc

Comment: A ok, debo enviar la imagen, el archivo completo a una API, de la cual redireccionar a un PHP que haria el resto del guardado